# Springboot controller request param for map always null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to pass in a bunch of id's to create a filter.

The incoming request looks like (ignoring the pagination stuff, which works fine)

```
http://localhost:8080/news-items?filter%5B%5D=09c731de-7ed8-385d-849c-f4d6535137ab&filter%5B%5D=dd1ba187-2df9-3985-ad1c-a4cde2dfe669&modelPath=controller.newsItems&page=0&per_page=25
```

Where the filter param equals an ID, but there is a bunch of them, for example:

```
filter: [
"09c731de-7ed8-385d-849c-f4d6535137ab",
"dd1ba187-2df9-3985-ad1c-a4cde2dfe669"
],
```

I can't seem to collect the filters in the controller. At the moment I have

```
public String getFeeds(@RequestParam(value = "filter", required = false) MultiValueMap<String, String> filter, @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) int page, @RequestParam(value = "per_page", required = false) int perPage) {
    log.info("Filter: {}", filter);
}
```

However filter is always null. I've tried using a String rather than a map but that is also always null.

How do I go about accepting an unknown number of params in this manner? I get the feeling this is really simple but I'm just missing the obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was simple like I thought. When using a Map in the `@RequestParam` it takes all the incoming params, regardless of what they are.

So from what I can tell the correct solution is to do something like

```
@GetMapping(produces = APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getFeeds(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> params) {

    params.forEach(//something);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is just an Array or a List, something like below :

```
public String getFeeds(@RequestParam(value = "filter", required = false) List<String> filters) { ... }
```